# How to multiply matrices with only one iterable

Tags: c, matrix

I have a matrix in the form below where the position is only given via one iterable (x).

```
 A       B
1 0     3 2
0 2     4 5
```

where for matrixA[x] and matrixB[x]

```
matrixA[0] = 1, matrixA[1] = 0, matrixA[2] = 0, matrixA[3] = 2
matrixB[0] = 3, matrixB[1] = 2 etc.
```

What would be the best way to implement a multiplication of matrices A and B (preferably in C) when the only way to receive the position within a matrix is through variable x (also have the length of width and height)?

(the examples I have gotten from google all use two variables - height and width to solve this however I'm only working with one)

Comment: you have `width` of matrices. yes ? if no, how you detect end of a row ? you must have been given I think.

Comment: @Emadpres yep I added that part in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think matrix's `width` had been given as input.

If so, You can convert `matrix[x][y]` to `matrix[x*width+y]` and apply any ordinary multiplication algorithm.